# How to redirect requests coming in port 80 of aws ec2 instance(windows server 2012 R2) to port 8085 for apache?

Tags: apache, redirect, amazon-ec2, port, wampserver

I have aws ec2 instance with Windows server 2012 and I am running a wamp server for a PHP web service. I want to redirect all the requests coming in the port 80 to 8085 as I have changed the apache server port from 80 to 8085. How can we redirect the requests coming from the port 80 to 8085? Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the following changes in the Apache configuration file  `/etc/httpd/conf`

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8085%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

After this just restart your Apache server.

```
service apache2 restart
```